# "News that matter" or "News that matters"?

Tags: pronunciation

I would like to ask which one is correct. This is for a slogan. I just cannot seem to understand which is the right one to use and why. Both sound fine to me, albeit the first one sounds better.

Comment: Would you ever have just one "new"?  If not then "news" is a collective noun and is generally regarded as singular.

Comment: In French  the word _nouvelle_ (new) can be used as a singular noun to mean 'an item of news', but in English only the plural _news_ is used and it is treated as an uncountable noun. It has to be "News that matters".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If your "news" is/are plural, then this is ***News that matter***, if not this is ***News that matters***.
The (s) of "matter" is affected by the noun before ***that***.

Comment: Thank you for the response, but I don't understand what you mean by "if your news is/are plural".

Comment: I think news is uncountable and therefore does not have a plural. It is always"News that matters".